# Casting a void pointer (that is part of a struct) into another pointer data type

Tags: c, parsing, lisp

I'm trying to figure out how to parse S-expressions in C on my own, in order to store data and code for my own rudimentary Lisp (written as a learning exercise, not for production).

Before explaining my code and my reasoning, I should explain that all I know about S-expressions is the introductory section of the Wikipedia article on it, and the occasional glance at Common Lisp code, so the naming of my structs and variables may be a bit off.

My language of implementation is C, and before I defined any functions I created the following structs:

```
typedef enum {
    string,
    letter,
    integer,
} atom_type;

typedef struct {
    void* blob;
    atom_type type;
} atom;

typedef struct expr {
    atom* current;
    struct expr* next;
} expr;
```

Each atom is stored in a struct `atom`, which contains a enum instance (? I'm not sure of the correct jargon for this) and a void pointer pointing to the data to be stored. Each S-expression "node" consists of a pointer to an atom and a pointer to the next S-expression node.

I've written a rudimentary function that accepts a string and parses it into an atom, like the following:

```
atom* parse_term(char* str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    atom* current = malloc(sizeof(atom));
    
    if(str[0] == '\'') {
        current->blob = (char*) &str[1];
        current->type = letter;
    } else if(str[0] == '\"') {
        char temp[256];
        int pos = 1;

        while(str[pos] != '\"') {
            temp[pos] = str[pos];
            pos++;
        }
        current->blob = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
        current->blob = (char*) &temp;
        current->type = string;
    } else if(isdigit(str[0])){
        char temp[256];
        int pos = 0;

        while(str[pos] != ' ') {
            temp[pos] = str[pos];
            pos++;
        }
        int tmp = atoi(temp);
        current->blob = (int*) &tmp;
        current->type = integer;
    }
    return current;
}
```

The function *seems* to be working correctly; at least, when I print out the data type it shows it correctly. But apart from this I can't figure out how to print out the actual 'blob': I've tried using the %p formatting code, as well as a switch statement:

```
void print_atom(atom* current) {
    switch(current->type) {
        case string:
            printf("atom%s\ttype:%d", current->blob, current->type);
        case letter:
            printf("atom%c\ttype:%d", current->blob, current->type);
        case integer:
            printf("atom%c\ttype:%d", current->blob, current->type);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. In the case of a string, it returns garbled text and in the case of everything else, it just doesn't print anything where the atom's information is supposed to be.

I imagine this is a product of my use of a void*  within a struct; how could I remedy this? I think I did cast properly (though I could very well be wrong, please tell me), the only other option I could concieve of is storing a hardcoded variable for every supported data type in the 'atom' struct, but this seems wasteful of resources.

Comment: The basic Lisp data type is the cons cell, which is used to represent lists.  It contains two symmetrical fields:  the car and the cdr, both of which point to S-expressions.  Cons cells are used to represent lists, but at their most basic they are just dotted pairs.  An S-expression can be a cons cell, a symbol, a string, a number, etc.

Comment: `current->blob = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));  current->blob = (char*) &temp;` = instant memory leak and eventually UB after `temp` is no longer viable. In fact, all of your code lines that store addresses to automatic local vars (temp, tmp), then later use those addresses outside of object lifetime are a recipe for *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.buildyourownlisp.com/ for more details/hints

Comment: BuildYourOwnLisp was what originally got me interested in Lisps - I purposefully chose not to follow that tutorial because it relied on a parser library, and the parser was the part I was looking forward to writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `void*`. Use a `union`. That's what `union`s are for.

In this example, I use an "anonymous union", which means that I can just refer to its fields as though they were directly inside the Atom struct. (I changed the spelling of names according to my prejudices, so that types are Capitalised and constants are ALLCAPS. I also separated the typedef and struct declarations for Atom, in case Atom turns out to be self-referential.

```c
typedef enum {
    STRING,
    LETTER,
    INTEGER
} AtomType;

typedef struct Atom Atom;
struct Atom {
    union {
      char* str;
      char  let;
      int   num;
    };
    AtomType type;
};

void print_atom(Atom* current) {
    switch(current->type) {
        case STRING:
            printf("atom %s\ttype:%d", current->str, current->type);
        case LETTER:
            printf("atom %c\ttype:%d", current->let, current->tyoe);
        case INTEGER:
            printf("atom %d\ttype:%d", current->num, current->type);
    }
}
```

As someone says in a comment, that's not actually how Lisp objects look. The usual implementation is combine cons cells and atoms, something like this (*instead of* `AtomType`). You'll also need to add `CELL` to your enum.

```c
typedef struct Cell Cell;
struct Cell {
    union {
        char* str;
        char  let;
        int   num;
        struct {
            Cell* hd; // Historic name: car
            Cell* tl; // Historic name: cdr
        };
    };
    CellType type;
};
```

Here there's an anonymous struct inside an anonymous union. Some people say this is confusing. Others (me, anyway) say it's less syntactic noise. Use your own judgement.

The use of `Cell*` inside the definition of `Cell` is the motivation for `typedef struct Cell Cell`.

You can play not-entirely-portable-but-usually-ok games to reduce the memory consumption of `Cell`, and most real implementations do. I didn't, because this is a learning experience.

---

Also note that real Lisps (and many toy ones) effectively avoid most parsing tasks; the language includes character macros which effectively do what parsing is needed (which isn't much); for the most part, they can be implemented in Lisp itself (although you need some way to bootstrap).